# correctly disposing a parameter

Tags: c#, dispose, idisposable

I have a code that up until now had a part like this:

```
public bool ActionA()
{
    using var dbContext = new MyDbContext();
    ...
}
```

The using statement disposes of the `dbContext` var at the end of its usage.

Now I want to change the signature with a DI:

```
 public bool ActionA(MyDbContext dbContext)
 {
    ...
 }
```

Is there a way to use the `using` statement on a parameter to dispose of it at the end of the usage automatically? If not, what is the correct way to dispose it?

Comment: Should be the caller responsability to dispose the parameter. Who is passing that parameter?

Comment: In general you should not dispose something that was passed to you from outside. Let the caller dispose it.

Comment: the code that is passing the parameter is also a code I own. So the simple solution is just moving the using statement outside and not bother with the disposing inside?

Comment: `public bool ActionA(MyDbContext dbContext) {...}` - someone's created the `dbContext` , and let you use it for a while; *do not dispose* - it may be used somewhere else.

Comment: Exactly passing a disposable object to another method is fine. But if the receiving method destroys the passed object then problems could occur on the calling side. Dispose where you create

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to use the using statement on a parameter to dispose of it at the end of the usage automatically?

Yes:

```
public bool ActionA(MyDbContext dbContext)
{
    using (dbContext)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, this is **bad**, because the caller may need to use the `MyDbContext` after `ActionA` has finished processing, potentially resulting in an `ObjectDisposedException`.

> what is the correct way to dispose it?

For the above reason, you should allow the caller to take responsibility for disposing that object.

DI frameworks will almost certainly take care of object disposal for you.

Answer (score 0):

In general its the callers responsibility. If you are using the default DI mechanism of .NET you need a scope to get an instance of a DbContext. If the scope is disposed all objects in the scope which are implementing IDisposable will be disposed automatically.